# How can I define control as a resource and then place it onto form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resources

I want to do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Button x:Key="butt" Content="Yeah!" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Place button here -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How to do it? I want to create library of small user controls in single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="butt"/>
</Grid>
```

Should work...

Comment: Cool! Didn't have a thought that it can be used outside of binding (markup expression).

Comment: @Poma: You can use all markup extensions with element syntax, this is quite useful in some cases such as this one. If you only use a converter in one place you can create it in the binding using this syntax for example.

Comment: dont forget to set Grid.Row and Column properties :)